# Syntax error when creating a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am creating a table where it has a foreign key so that it would be linked to another table, but it kept me giving this error, I already checked the syntax on w3schools, but I still keep getting errors any idea why? here's my SQL script

```
CREATE TABLE user_profile
(
user_Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
accnt_id INT,
first_name varchar(255),
last_name varchar(255),
biography TEXT,
date_joined DATETIME,
date_of_birth DATE,
email varchar(255),
gender varchar(255),
screenname varchar(255)
country varchar(255),
FOREIGN KEY (accnt_Id) REFERENCES accounts(accnt_Id)
)
```

Here's the error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'country varchar(255), FOREIGN KEY (accnt_Id) REFERENCES accounts(accnt_Id) )' at line 13
```

Comment: a. does the accounts table have `accnts_Id` field. b. both the tables have InnoDB engine?

Comment: I am using the one in PHPmyadmin, with the latest build

Comment: @T-ShirtDude the accounts table has an innoDB engine, this table I don't know since I am creating it manually through my script

Comment: The syntax error is _before_ the constraint, right before "country"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `,` behind `screenname varchar(255)` change it to

```
screenname varchar(255),
```

and it should works.

Comment: wouldn't it be in front of screename?

Comment: no man, it must be how i wrote. screenname is not last column so then behind declaration of column must be comma.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma after the 'screenname' column

```
CREATE TABLE user_profile
(
    user_Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    accnt_id INT,
    first_name varchar(255),
    last_name varchar(255),
    biography TEXT,
    date_joined DATETIME,
    date_of_birth DATE,
    email varchar(255),
    gender varchar(255),
    screenname varchar(255),
    country varchar(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (accnt_Id) REFERENCES accounts(accnt_Id)
)
```